# Send JSON from rsyslog to Kibana

Tags: json, logstash, kibana, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using rsyslog to watch over my syslogs and send them over to Logstash+Kibana.

My syslogs messages are logged as JSON. They can look something like this:

```
{"foo":"bar", "timegenerated": 43843274834}
```

rsyslog configuration as so:

```
module(load="omelasticsearch")

#define a template to print all fields of the message
template(name="messageToES" type="list" option.json="on") {
  property(name="msg")
}
*.* action(type="omelasticsearch"
       server="localserverhere"
       serverport="80"
       template="messageToES")
```

The Kibana is fine, since if I run a CURL command to it, it receives the record. The code as below:

```
curl -XPOST myserver/test/bar -d '{"test": "baz", "timegenerated":1447145221519}'
```

When I run rsyslogs and point it to a dummy server, I can see the incoming requests with the valid json. However, when I point it back to my logstash server, it doesn't show up in logstash or kibana.

Does anyone know how to send syslogs as json into Kibana/logstash?

Comment: You don't "send" anything to kibana, but rather send it to elasticsearch and let kibana query it for you.

Comment: Check your logstash and elasticsearch logs.  Add a stdout{} output stanza to logstash to see what it thinks.  Turn up debugging in logstash (command line flag).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but it looks like you are missing things from your config file.  The docs have a pretty thorough example:

```
module(load="omelasticsearch")
template(name="testTemplate"
     type="list"
     option.json="on") {
       constant(value="{")
         constant(value="\"timestamp\":\"")      property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
         constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg")
         constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")        property(name="hostname")
         constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
         constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
         constant(value="\",\"syslogtag\":\"")   property(name="syslogtag")
       constant(value="\"}")
     }
action(type="omelasticsearch"
   server="myserver.local"
   serverport="9200"
   template="testTemplate"
   searchIndex="test-index"
   searchType="test-type"
   bulkmode="on"
   queue.type="linkedlist"
   queue.size="5000"
   queue.dequeuebatchsize="300"
   action.resumeretrycount="-1")
```

Based on what you are trying to do, it looks like you need to plug in `localserverhere` where it shows `myserver.local`.  It also looks like you have ES accepting stuff on port 80, so you'd put in `80` instead of `9200`.